# Is there a technical reason for a maximum password length rule (15 to 100 characters)?

Tags: passwords, password-policy

I've seen on many sites in the registration page that the password should have also a maximum length (between 15 and 100 characters). Except for DDOS attacks, is there a reason for this rule, giving the fact that the password will be hashed and only the hash will be stored?

Comment: To reduce the probability of the user forgetting the (long) password and sending in frequent Forgot Password requests? Most likely not the real reason but just thinking out loud...

Comment: Not a dupe, the linked question (and answer) are specifically about 8 character password limits.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is legacy.

Comment: So my conclusion is: Legacy and customer support load.